# What is the nginx equivalent of worker and prefork MPMs in Apache?

Tags: apache2, nginx, apache

I'm seriously considering the switch from Apache to nginx, and I'd like to understand nginx better - I'm no Apache guru either, so I think I'll learn more about Apache in the answers to these questions. I think it will be apparent from my questions that I really have a lot to learn in this area and have probably misunderstood much. But that's why I'm asking:

1. So does nginx have no equivalent of Apache's prefork MPM? If so,
   then how is nginx different from the worker MPM? And if it's like
   the worker MPM, then why aren't there the same concerns about thread
   safety which make people not use Apache's mod_php with a worker MPM?
2. If a process is an OS process, and a process can
   have multiple threads (similar to Java where java executable is the
   single process and it can start multiple threads), how do
   'requests' fit into this model? I understand that a client
   request doesn't result in a new OS process with nginx, but does it result in a
   new thread or can a thread handle multiple simultaneous requests? Or if not, then multiple sequential connections where when a thread has finished with one request it can handle another?
3. What is the relationships between 'requests' and 'connections'? If a client makes 10 requests, are these 10 connections, or is it 1 connection? How long does a connection last? I realize that if a client makes 10 requests over a period of a month, those could be part of the same session (if the session cookie persists), but surely that wouldn't be the same connection. So where's the line drawn for what constitutes a connection?
4. What are the different ways of using PHP from nginx? Unless I'm
   mistaken, Apache has 3 (mod_php, mod_fastcgi, and mod_fcgid). For
   nginx I've heard of PHP-FPM and FastCGI. Are there other options or
   are these the only 2 ways, and if so how do they differ from each
   other? I keep reading the PHP-FPM is *another way* of doing FastCGI
   so I'm not exactly sure what the difference is.
5. If there are 10 clients connected to the server accessing PHP pages,
   how many processes will I see when running the 'top' command if using
   nginx, and what will they be named? (I imagine the answer depends on the response to the question in the previous paragraph.) If this was with Apache prefork MPM and
   mod_php, if I understand correctly then I think I'd see 10 httpd
   processes when running 'top'.
6. How many ports on my server will now be occupied? Before it was just port 80 by Apache. Now I imagine there'll be port 80 by nginx, plus some other port for nginx to communicate with the thing that's actually processing the PHP. And what exactly is that thing that runs the PHP, is it the 'PHP' executable, or 'FastCGI', or something else?
7. So if nginx is configured to use multiple 'backend' PHP processors (is this possible?) how many APC instances will there be? And how would requests from nginx be handed to them (e.g. would it use the session cookie to send the same user back to the same PHP processor?)

So many questions, I know, but hopefully some out there who actually understand all this can help me understand as well. I really want to! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This article should answer pretty much everything: http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2011/11/a-faster-web-server-ripping-out-apache-for-nginx.ars about Apache v.s. Nginx

As for the other questions:

3) A request is just that, a request for some resource on the server. `GET /index.html` is one request. `POST /formhandler.php` is another request. A connection is the literally TCP socket setup that links the client browser to the server. A connection is what the request will travel through. One connection can handle multiple requests, or it can handle only one request. It depends on if HTTP Keep-Alives are allowed/requested, and what mood the client and server are in that day. Best case, 1 connection handles 10 requests, requiring only one TCP handshake sequence. Worst case, each request goes over a separate connection, requiring 10 tcp handshakes.

6) There'll be one or two listening ports open on the server (port 80 for regular, 443 for ssl, maybe). Any number of requests can be multiplexed onto a single port. There'll never be LESS than one port held open by the webserver, but should never really be more than 1 or 2 either.